# Can not Connected to Asterisk AMI from Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, asterisk, asteriskami

I have code like this

```
$asm = new AGI_AsteriskManager;
if(!($asm->connect('192.168.1.14','admin','123'))){
    echo "can not connect to AMI";
     exit;
}else {
    echo 'AMI connected';
}
```

When I use this code on native PHP, It's show me `AMI connected` but when I use  this code in laravel method,It show me `can not connect to AMI`
My laravel method:

```
public function call(){
   $asm = new AGI_AsteriskManager;
    if(!($asm->connect('192.168.1.14','admin','123'))){
        echo "can not connect to AMI";
         exit;
    }else {
        echo 'AMI connected';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you execute both codes on the same machine? (i could just guess and maybe something with vagrant/docker so that the ip is not reachable from within your laravel application)

Comment: @RolandStarke Yes of  Course

Answer (score 2):

This might be the problem of changing file structure in native php and laravel

`new AGI_AsteriskManager` will check class in current namespace, I think you should use `\`

```
$asm = new \AGI_AsteriskManager;
```

Comment: I test it but not work correctly. method create instance of  object . when I `prinr_r($asm)` show me `Customer\Controller\AGI_AsteriskManager Object ( [config] => [socket] => [server] => [port] => [pagi] => [event_handlers:Customer\Controller\AGI_AsteriskManager:private] => [_buffer:Customer\Controller\AGI_AsteriskManager:private] => [_logged_in:Customer\Controller\AGI_AsteriskManager:private] => )`

Comment: check its output lie `$res = $asm->connect('192.168.1.14','admin','123');` and `print_r($res);` ?

Comment: On native php when  I use incorrect user or pass show me `can not connect to AMI` but on laravel both them show this error

Comment: please add this `$res = $asm->connect('192.168.1.14','admin','123'); and print_r($res);` inside your function after `$asm = new AGI_AsteriskManager;` and share the output ?

Comment: is your laravel in your local machine on hosted any where else ? ip `192.168.1.14` look like as local machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181078/discussion-between-paranoid-and-c2486).